# Is it possible to force EF (Code First) to ignore derived types when constructing the final SQL

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

If I have this as my TPT model:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set;  }
}

[Table("Bars")]
public class Bar : Foo
{
    public string MoreText { get; set; }
}
```

and a derived DbContext like this:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

Then when I execute a query on Foo the final SQL will include an outer join to Bar.

For example:

```
uisng(var context = new MyContext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(context.Foos.ToString());
}
```

will result in this as the final SQL Statement

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN ( NOT (([Project1].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project1].[C1] IS NOT NULL))) THEN
'0X' ELSE '0X0X' END AS [C1],
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
[Extent1].[Text] AS [Text],
CASE WHEN ( NOT (([Project1].[C1] = 1) AND ([Project1].[C1] IS NOT NULL))) THEN
CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) ELSE [Project1].[MoreText] END AS [C2]
FROM  [dbo].[Foos] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT
        [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id],
        [Extent2].[MoreText] AS [MoreText],
        cast(1 as bit) AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Bars] AS [Extent2] ) AS [Project1] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Proj
ect1].[Id]
```

I do understand why --- doing so allows me to do something like:

```
foreach(var x in context.Foos)
{
    if(x is Bar) Console.WriteLine("Impressive");
    else Console.WriteLine("Not so much");
}
```

However as you you can imagine this kind of query over base classes can quickly result in nightmarish queries for SQL Server to process.  Hence the question.

Is it possible to inform Linq to EF 5.0 that it should bring back only the base type and not the derived type. therefore making the final SQL much simpler?

Comment: Have you tried using `OfType` - e.g. `context.Foos.OfType<Foo>()`? I am not sure if it will make the generated SQL Statement simpler though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with Linq to Entities. Linq to entities offers `OfType` but it uses .NET rules for type inheritance so if you use `OfType<Foo>` you will still get both `Foo` and `Bar` instances because `Bar` is of type `Foo`.

Entity SQL (which is not available in code first and DbContext API - you must access it through ObjectContext API) is more powerful because it is not dependent on limited functionality offered by Linq. It offers construct `OFTYPE ONLY` which can return only instances of `Foo` but I believe it will not make the query simpler because to find which types are only `Foo` and not `Bar` it still have to make a join. If you expect to get instance of `Foo` even if the object is `Bar` you will not achieve that with EF - entity type is immutable. You cannot change the type in query.

The simplest workaround to use `OfType` and Linq is to define `Foo` as abstract and add additional derived type. You will always query a real type with `OfType` and it should ensure that you don't have joins with unnecessary tables.

Comment: I'm not sure how it would work that I could query for Foo if it's abstract.

Comment: That is the point - you would not query for a `Foo` but for a derived type. If you want only properties from `Foo` and you actually don't care what the real type is you have to use projection.